# MariaDB Galera cluster

Tags: mariadb

Insert data into MySql DB from client(eg: 1000 inserts). While the insert happens, I stop DB which results in error state.How to resolve this? I need the remaining insert to happen once the DB is up and running. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What error state?  What value of autocommit?  Did you `COMMIT`?  Did you check for errors from the `COMMIT`?  Was that a single `INSERT` statement with 1000 rows?  Where there errors on the other nodes?  Or is this a single node "cluster"?

Comment: @Rick **Architecture:**  3 node galera cluster (active-active) with HAproxy for load balancing. HAproxy uses Round robin to chose between nodes. Insert query is ran from a file eg:'mysql -u root -h 192.168.1.2 -p -P 3306 < query.txt'.Assume Haproxy chooses node 1,while the query is ongoing, I manually stop the mysql service. Which causes _ERROR 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock_.The result is only some of the rows get inserted. My question is , I want a solution by which i can insert all the data by using other active nodes in the cluster.

Comment: "some of rows get inserted" -- sounds like you do not have the 1000 rows in a transaction?  Or are you saying that some rows are inserted by each of the nodes?

Comment: The client _must_ check for errors after every `INSERT` _and_ `COMMIT`.  If 'deadlock' is detected, the 'right' thing to do is to retry the transaction.  This implies hitting HAProxy again, and (hopefully) getting a node that is still up.